# What's the difference between groups and group in the re module?

Tags: python, regex

Here it is:

```
import re
>>>s = 'abc -j k -l m'
>>>m = re.search('-\w+ \w+', s)
>>>m.groups()
()
>>> m.group(0)
'-j k'
```

Why `groups()` gives me nothing, but `group(0)` yields some? What is the difference?

**Follow Up**

Code is as follows

```
>>>re.findall('(-\w+ \w+)', s)
['-j k', '-l m', '-n o']
```

`findall` can get me all the `-\w+ \w+` substrings, but look at this:

```
>>>m = re.search('(-\w+ \w+)+', s)
>>>m.groups()
('-j k',)
```

Why can't `search` give me all the substrings?

**Follow Up Again**

If `s = 'abc -j k -l m -k o`, and

```
>>>m = re.search(r'(-\w+ \w+ )+', s)
>>>m.groups()
('-l m ',)      # why just one substring?
>>>m.group(0)
'-j k -l m '    # as I expected
```

Comment: The standard behavior in most regular expression flavors is to *replace* any content of a group when it is captured more than once instead of generating extra groups for each pass. If you want to capture all of them you'll have to search repeatedly. `re.findall()` should be useful in your case.

Comment: @danielkza, but why `groups()` gave me `'-l m '` not `'-j k '`?

Comment: The first pass of the repetition matched `-j k `. The second pass then overwrote the stored match with a new one, `-l m`. If there were even more matches following, the last would be the one stored. I couldn't tell you *why* this behavior exists, but it is present in virtually all regular expression flavors. If you want to capture all the matches you have to apply the pattern multiple times.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`groups()` only returns any explicitly-captured groups in your regex (denoted by `(` round brackets `)` in your regex), whereas `group(0)` returns the entire substring that's matched by your regex regardless of whether your expression has any capture groups.

The first explicit capture in your regex is indicated by `group(1)` instead.

Re follow-up edit:

> Why can't `search` give me all the substrings?

`search()` will only return the first match against the pattern in your input string.

Comment: @Alcott: I added a follow-up answer.

Comment: @Joel Cornett: I was getting bored of "parentheses".

Comment: But look at what I put in `search`. I wrote `re.search('(-\w+ \w+)+', s)`, see? There is a `+` right after the pattern `(-\w+ \w+)`. So I suppose the search should give me more than one substrings matching the pattern, right?

Comment: @Alcott: Your first set of `-\w+ \w+` is directly followed by a space, which isn't covered by the pattern, so it can't look past your first substring.

Answer (score 9):

Let me explain with a small example

```
>>> var2 = "Welcome 44 72"
>>> match = re.search(r'Welcome (\d+) (\d+)',var2)
>>> match.groups()
('44', '72')
>>> match.groups(0)
('44', '72')
>>> match.groups(1)
('44', '72')
>>> match.group(0)
'Welcome 44 72'
>>> match.group(1)
'44'
```

Explanation: `groups()` is a tuple type which has all the values which are pattern matched with your regular expression.

`groups(0)` or `groups()` or `groups(1)` .... It only prints all the values

group() or group(0) -> It will give entire string along with the value which is pattern matched with your regular expression.

group(1) will give first pattern matched value

group(2) will give second pattern matched value....

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex has no match groups, indicated by parens (`(...)`).