# Apart from returning string and iterator in re.findall() and re.finditer() in python do their working also differ?

Tags: python, regex

Wrote the following code so that i get all variable length patterns matching str_key.

```
line = "ABCDABCDABCDXXXABCDXXABCDABCDABCD"
str_key = "ABCD"
regex = rf"({str_key})+"

find_all_found = re.findall(regex,line)
print(find_all_found)

find_iter_found = re.finditer(regex, line)
for i in find_iter_found:
    print(i.group())
```

Output i got:

```
['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'ABCD']
ABCDABCDABCD
ABCD
ABCDABCDABCD
```

The intended output is last three lines printed by finditer(). I was expecting both functions to give me same output(list or callable does not matter). why it differs in findall() as far i understood from other posts already on stackoverflow, these two functions differ only in their return types and not in matching patterns. Do they work differently, if not what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access `groups` rather than `group`.

```
>>> find_iter_found = re.finditer(regex, line)
>>> for i in find_iter_found:
...     print(i.groups()[0])
```

The difference between the two methods is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347950/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-group-in-the-re-module).

The behaviour of the two functions is pretty much the same as far as the matching process is concerned as per:

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
> strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
> in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
> return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
> has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.
>
> *Changed in version 3.7: Non-empty matches can now start just after a
> previous empty match.*
>
> re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping
> matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned
> left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty
> matches are included in the result.
>
> *Changed in version 3.7: Non-empty matches can now start just after a
> previous empty match.*

Comment: The correct output is one given by finditer() i.e. last three lines of my output. What I am confused is, why findall() is not giving me same output as finditer() although in list format.

Comment: As posted by 'Toto' I have to change the regex, but if they both search the same way why i should change the regex?

Comment: You have to understand that `ABCD` is a match and while `ABCDABCD` is also a match is not "non-overalpping" so you're not supposed to get your "desired output". It just so happens that since you get actual match objects with the iterator you are able to also get the "largest group" that satisfies the regex. Check out the behaviour of group and groups to understand this better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot. I made a mistake understanding Overlapping and Non overlapping.

Comment: In your specific case (ABCD)+ note that the plus is outside of the group. Consider: `>>> re.findall(r"((ABCD)+)", line)` and its result:
`[('ABCDABCDABCD', 'ABCD'), ('ABCD', 'ABCD'), ('ABCDABCDABCD', 'ABCD')]`

Answer (score 1):

For `re.findall` change your regex

- `regex = rf"({str_key})+"`

into

- `regex = rf"((?:{str_key})+)"`.

The quantifier `+` have to **inside** the capture group.

Comment: Yes it worked, but as replied by 'rudolfovic' the behavior of the two functions is pretty much the same as far as the matching process is concerned then why I have to change the regex? My regex should have worked in both the cases.

Comment: @Mod: `(...)+` matches a single capture group n times, by construction this gives you the last value captured, `((?:...)+)` matches n times the non-capture group and return the whole match in group 1. Those 2 regex are totaly different.

Comment: Thank you for regex and explanation.